# HttpClient : http 2 request sent via proxy has no upgrade headers

Tags: java, proxy, http2

So, I am managing a company http server and have been asked to upgrade the server to support proxy requests using http 2 protocol

This is the test client. I am using [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html?msclkid=cd54d5c7c88411ecb4c9d5cfd8ea4129) in jdk 17. Here is the test case.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
     {
      HttpClient client=HttpClient.newBuilder()
                                  .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.2",1000))) //proxy to 192.168.1.2:1000 
                                  .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)    //use http 2                      
                                  .build();
      
      //request to 192.168.1.2:2000
      HttpRequest request=HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("http://192.168.1.2:2000/Test.txt"))
                                      .build();
      
      HttpResponse response=client.send(request,BodyHandlers.ofString());
      System.out.println("Status code: " + response.statusCode());                            
      System.out.println("Headers: " + response.headers().map());
      System.out.println("Body: " + response.body());
     }
```

My server is running on http 2 protocol and I wasn't getting any response. Upon debugging the packet received on my server looked like this:

```
    GET http://192.168.1.2:2000/Test.txt HTTP/1.1
    Content-Length: 0
    Host: 192.168.1.2:2000
    User-Agent: Java-http-client/17.0.2
```

This is neither in http 2 format nor are there any upgrade headers which my server was designed to parse, which typically looks like this without using proxy:

```
    GET /Test.txt HTTP/1.1
    Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
    Content-Length: 0
    Host: 192.168.1.2:2000
    HTTP2-Settings: AAEAAEAAAAIAAAABAAMAAABkAAQBAAAAAAUAAEAA
    Upgrade: h2c
    User-Agent: Java-http-client/17.0.2
```

My server was designed to parse this request as it is the [upgrade request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540?msclkid=198be25fc87b11eca21146cdba8d08f5#section-3.2) which contains the http 2 settings for the client.

So, my questions are when I get a request like this:

```
     GET http://192.168.1.2:2000/Test.txt HTTP/1.1
     Content-Length: 0
     Host: 192.168.1.2:2000
     User-Agent: Java-http-client/17.0.2
```

1. Do I respond back to the client in HTTP 1.1 or HTTP 2 Format? The doubt arises because in my client test case I have clearly specified version(HTTP_2) but the request has no upgrade headers, so should I maybe respond back in HTTP 1.1 format?
2. Is there any way to make the HttpClient include the Upgrade headers so I can respond back in HTTP 2 format?

**EDIT.**

To debug the response i created an simple TCP server running on port 1000 and proxied through it. I simply print the bytes received at this proxy and get the exact same output

```
//Test Proxy server running on port 1000. No parsing data simply print and close for debugging purposes
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
 {
  try(ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(1000))
  {
   try(Socket client=server.accept())
   {
    try(InputStream input=client.getInputStream())
    {
     byte[] data=new byte[8196];
     int length=input.read(data);
     System.out.println(new String(data,0,length));
    } 
   } 
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Your client is using a proxy. You are sending the request to the proxy and the proxy forwards it (with any modifications) to the server. Maybe the proxy is the problem here?

Comment: The output was retrieved as raw bytes straight from the sockets before the proxy even had a chance to see it. To test your theory i created an simple TCP server which simply printed the bytes received and closed the connection and i got the exact same output

Comment: the linked documentation indicates that version 2 is already the default and there is a note: `Constraints may also affect the selection of protocol version. For example, if HTTP/2 is requested through a proxy, and if the implementation does not support this mode, then HTTP/1.1 may be used`  It looks like your code is ok.

Comment: So HttpClient does not support http 2 protocol over proxy? Is there anything setting to change that or should it be reported as an feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, OpenJDK's `HttpClient` is only able to send HTTP/1.1 requests to a proxy.

Even if you specified `HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2`, because there is a proxy, OpenJDK's `HttpClient` ignores the version you specified, formats the request as HTTP/1.1 and sends it to the proxy.

OpenJDK's `HttpClient` proxy capabilities are quite limited (for example, you cannot easily use a secure protocol to communicate to the proxy), so you may want to look into different HTTP clients.

[Disclaimer, I'm part of the Jetty team.]

Jetty's `HttpClient` supports a more flexible proxy configuration, so you can  specify what protocol the proxy speaks (and whether it is secure).

Note that you need the proxy cooperation to obtain what you want, because `Connection` is a [hop-by-hop header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-6.1), so it is only valid on a single hop, i.e. from the client to the proxy.

The proxy can legitimately take the client's HTTP/1.1 upgrade request to HTTP/2, but then use HTTP/1.1 to talk to the server, get the HTTP/1.1 response back from the server and produce a `101 Upgrade` response followed by the an HTTP/2 response obtained converting to HTTP/2 the server's HTTP/1.1 response:

```
client                    proxy               server
   | ----  h1+upgrade  ---> |                    |
   |                        | --  h1 request --> |
   |                        | <-- h1 response -- |
   | <-- h1 101 upgrade  -- |
   | <--- h2c response  --- |
```

A proxy that supports `h2c` could instead do what you want:

```
client                     proxy                    server
   | ----  h1+upgradeA  ---> |                        |
   |                         | ---  h1+upgradeB  ---> |
   |                         | <--  h1 101 upgrade -- |
   |                         | <--- h2c response ---- |
   | <--  h1 101 upgrade  -- |
   | <--- h2c response  ---- |
```

Note however that `upgradeA` could be different from `upgradeB` exactly because `Connection` and `Upgrade` are hop-by-hop headers, and the proxy may have a different HTTP/2 configuration with respect to the client (and therefore also send a different `HTTP2-Settings` header).

If the communication between the client and the proxy is clear-text, you must have prior knowledge of whether the proxy supports `h2c`, otherwise the client will default to HTTP/1.1 (like OpenJDK's `HttpClient` does).
In contrast, Jetty's `HttpClient` can be configured with the protocol you want to use to talk to the proxy.

Alternatively, you have to use a secure communication via TLS so that the client and the proxy can negotiate the protocol they want to speak (e.g. `h2`).

The same holds for the proxy: if the communication with the server is clear-text (your case), the proxy must have prior knowledge that the server supports `h2c`, so you need to configure the proxy with that information, otherwise the proxy will likely default to HTTP/1.1.

Obviously the proxy must support both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

If you are implementing the proxy, copying the `Connection` (and other hop-by-hop headers) towards the server is technically wrong, but it may work in restricted, simpler, cases.
See [this section of RFC 7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-6.1) that specifies how hop-by-hop headers should be removed by proxies.

FTR, [this test](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-11.0.9/tests/test-http-client-transport/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/client/ProxyWithDynamicTransportTest.java#L218) shows that Jetty (client and server) can support any combination of protocols (HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2, clear-text and secure) between the client, the proxy and the server.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I have issued an feature request for proxy support 2.0 and have no plans of waiting on them. I'll look into your client library

Comment: The feature request became a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8285972) report